# Вывести только название файла миниатюры WP

Tags: wordpress

Приветствую.

У кастомного типа записей появилась необходимость получить не миниатюру, а только её название filename.jpg.
Предполагаю, что нужно сначала получить всю ссылку через get_the_post_thumbnail_url и потом отсечь перед выводом всё лишнее, но как это реализовать кодом?
Или может есть более правильные способы получить название файла миниатюры?

Answer (score 0):

Вот так можно сделать:

```
$uri = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post_id ); // вернет http://mysite.ru/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/my-cool-picture.jpg
$path = parse_url($uri, PHP_URL_PATH); // вернет     /my-cool-picture.jpg
$filename = substr($path, 1); // убрать первый символ
```